# blur event not working on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little script that checks to see if a form is valid before enabling the Submit button:

```
$('#RegisterForm input').on('keyup blur', function () { 
    if ($('#RegisterForm').valid()) 
    {                   
        EnableSubmitButton();
    } 
    else
    {
        DisableSubmitButton();
    }
});
```

This works perfectly, except for on the dropdowns.  If they are the last item to be completed, doing so does not trigger the `EnableSubmitButton()` method. And unlike the other inputs, if you un-selected it (or, in the case of a textbox, clear the contents) then the `DisableSubmitButton();` event does not trigger.

However, if you try and submit the form without the dropdown selected, it WILL trigger the `Required` error inside the  $("#RegisterForm").validate() method.

```
<select 
    class="form-control input-sm required error" 
    id="CountryId" 
    name="CountryId" 
    aria-required="true" 
    aria-invalid="true">
        <option value="">Country*</option>
        <option value="1">United States</option>
        ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original selector is matching only elements of type `<input>` which does not include `<select>`.

You can modify your selector to include both element types:

`$('#RegisterForm input, #RegisterForm select')...`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script from this:

```
$('#RegisterForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
```

To this:

```
$('#RegisterForm input').on('keyup blur change', function () {
```

And that still didn't work.  But, this does work:

```
    // and for some reason, this dropdown isn't getting captured in the method above, so it gets it's own
    $("#CountryId").change(function () {
        if ($('#RegisterForm').valid()) {
            EnableSubmitBUtton();
        } else {
            DisableSubmitButton();
        }
    });
```

Seems like a stupid hack, but it gets the job done.  Open to other answers.

Comment: but `$('#RegisterForm input')` selector doesn't match `<select>` ... ? should be `$("#RegisterForm select")` no?

Comment: ah, i see.  So how would one make this work with both inputs and selects?  Can you specify both?: `$('#RegisterForm input select')`

Comment: You could try your original code with both selectors: `$('#RegisterForm input, #RegisterForm select')...`

Comment: That's it!  Can you make that an answer?  I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown should be inside the Form field.Then blur event will work.